# PHP preg_replace url get parameters in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Thanks to @s.d.a.p.e I've come a step close but I'm not quite there yet.

What I'm trying to do is replace all instances of a string in a block of text.  I want to replace something like this:

```
user is ?user_id=34&first_name=Ralph so is ?user_id=1 also
```

With this:

```
user is /user/34/ so is /user/1/ also
```

Here is the preg_replace code I'm using:

```
$pattern = '#\?user_id=([0-9]+)#';
$replace = '/user/$1/';
echo preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$string);
```

With that pattern I end up with this:

```
user is /user/34/&first_name=Ralph so is /user/1/ also
```

Thanks again.

Comment: anything you tried already?

Comment: @RST, yes.  I was actually going through my history finding close examples.  I'll get those posted in a few minutes.

Comment: print preg_replace('#\?user_id=([0-9]+)\&(first_name=(?:.*))#','/user/$1?$2','?user_id=34&first_name=Ralph');

Comment: I've update my answer, it works as you want.

Comment: `preg_replace('~\?user_id\=(\d+)\S*~i', '/user/$1/', $string);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$string = "user is ?user_id=34&first_name=Ralph so is ?user_id=1 also";
$result = preg_replace('/\?(user)_id=(\d+)(.*?)(?! )/i', '/$1/$2/$3', $string );

echo $result ;
```

Output:

```
user is /user/34/&first_name=Ralph so is /user/1/ also
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/j9m5pj)

Answer (score 1):

```
print preg_replace(
   '#\?user_id=([0-9]+)\&(first_name=(?:.*))#',
   '/user/$1?$2',
   '?user_id=34&first_name=Ralph'
);
```

---

result :

```
/user/34?first_name=Ralph  if get it right..
```

Comment: for `/user/34` remove `?$2`

Comment: This is extremely close, but when I remove ?$2, it doesn't continue on with the string and stops at /user/34.  "user is ?user_id=34&first_name=Ralph and hes a user." is the

Answer (score 1):

I'd use this:

```
$string = 'user is ?user_id=34&first_name=Ralph so is ?user_id=1 also';
$pattern = '#\?user_id=([0-9]+)\S*#';
$replace = '/user/$1/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

Where `\S` stands for any character that is not a space.

**Output:**

```
user is /user/34/ so is /user/1/ also
```